# How to stop multiprocess in spyder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I Have a for loop get data from a request GET call to an API for roughly ~250k urls.

This is the code so far:

```
lst = ['url.com','url2.com']

lst2 = []

from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def some_fun(url):
    for i in lst:
    #print (row)
        xml_data1 = requests.get(i).text
        lst2.append(xml_data1)
        #time.sleep(1)
        print(xml_data1) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c_pool = ThreadPool(16) #add as many as threads you can
    c_pool.map(some_fun, lst)
    c_pool.close()
    c_pool.join()
```

The issue is when I go to stop the code via the keyboard, I see the Ipython console stop and go to the next line but not the multiprocess output, which keeps running and appending in the list.

How do I stop the multiprocess once it has begun?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "stop the code via the keyboard" is this `ctrl` + `.`?

Comment: Moreover, are you sure you get a performance improvement compared to single threading? (GIL limits a python process to run only one thread at a time, so multithreading is efficient only in application where the threads execution does not use python, but for instance, C, i.E. numpy, openCV).

Comment: @roganjosh `multiprocessing.dummy` is a copy of the library `multiprocessing` for threads. It is `multithreading`. No mistake on that part.

Comment: @mathieu yep, I'm wrong. Thanks for that.

Comment: @roganjosh I stopped the keyboard by the red button in the ipython console, however which is the same is `ctrl` + `.` I am very new to multiprocessing/threading so any suggestion is helpful.

Comment: @Mathieu I am very new to multithreading/processing any help is great.

Comment: @roganjosh & Mathieu the output just stopped after some time, why is this?

Comment: @RustyShackleford Sadly I can't help you much on this topic. I'm already quite surprise that you manage to use either one of those in spyder. In my case, I'm using multiprocessing quite often, and it can't be used inside the spyder IDE. I would just launch the file through the windows cmd. If for any reason I want to interrupt the program, I just spam Ctrl+C and close the cmd which will result in a crash of the process...

Comment: @Mathieu I am on mac, but no worries thank you

Comment: @RustyShackleford well replace cmd by terminal ^^'